# On cluster messages trigger class function

Tags: javascript, node.js, worker

im experimenting currently with cluster and worker (child_process).
im trying to bind my class to "process.on" function, but it isnt working...

```
var coresCount = require('os').cpus().length;
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cluster = require('cluster');
class Listen extends Command {

    async trigger (args, options) {
        if (cluster.isMaster) {
            for (var i = 0; i < coresCount; i++) {
                cluster.fork();
            }
        } else {
            process.on('message', function(msg) {
                this._test()
            }).bind(this);
        }
    }

    _test() {
        console.log('test')
    }
}

module.exports = Listen
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: this._test is not a function
```

could anybody give me a little hint, or what would be the best practice to work with the messages?

Thanks Advance

Comment: i got the same error message "TypeError: this._test is not a function" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `bind` on the result of `process.on`. You should be calling `bind` on your event handler callback. Change it to this:

```
process.on('message', function(msg) {
    this._test()
}.bind(this));
```

Or:

```
process.on('message', msg => {
    this._test()
});
```